# Joins with Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm learning a bit of Laravel coming over from Symfony, and i'm a little confused with how joins work with eloquent. so that i have have the returned object as my model class rather than a `stdClass`.

Currently i am doing this:

```
$query = DB::table('caravan')
            ->join('type','caravan.type_id', '=', 'type.id')
            ->join('category','caravan.category_id', '=', 'category.id')
            ->where('type.name','=', 'New')
            ->where('category.name', '=', ucwords(strtolower($category)))
            ->orderBy($orderBy,$order);
```

This works, it brings through all the correct records with the joined columns, but i don't want it to be a `stdClass`.

My caravan model looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne;

/**
 * Class Caravan
 * @package App\Models
 * @property int $stock
 * @property int $branch_id
 * @property int $category_id
 * @property int $type_id
 * @property string $reg
 * @property string $make
 * @property string $model
 * @property string $specification
 * @property string $derivative
 * @property string $engine_size
 * @property string $engine_type
 * @property string $transmission
 * @property string $colour
 * @property int $year
 * @property int $mileage
 * @property boolean $commercial
 * @property double $sales_siv
 * @property double $retail
 * @property double $web_price
 * @property string $sub_heading;
 * @property string $advertising_notes
 * @property string $manager_comments
 * @property double $previous_price
 * @property double $guide_retail_price
 * @property boolean $available_for_sale
 * @property boolean $advertised_on_own_website
 * @property int $berths
 * @property int $axles
 * @property string $layout_type
 * @property double $width
 * @property double $length
 * @property double $height
 * @property int $kimberley_unit_id
 * @property \DateTime $kimberley_date_updated
 *
 */
class Caravan extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $table = 'caravan';

    /**
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'kimberley_date_updated' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s',
        'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s',
        'updated_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s',
        'web_price' => 'decimal: 2',
        'previous_price' => 'decimal: 2'
    ];


    /**
     * @return HasOne
     */
    public function category() : HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Category::class, 'id', 'category_id');
    }

    /**
     * @return HasOne
     */
    public function type() : HasOne
    {
        die("DD");
        return $this->hasOne(Type::class, 'id', 'type_id');
    }
    
    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getStock(): int
    {
        return $this->stock;
    }


    /**
     * @param int $stock
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setStock(int $stock): self
    {
        $this->stock = $stock;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getBranchId(): int
    {
        return $this->branch_id;
    }


    /**
     * @param int $branch_id
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setBranchId(int $branch_id): self
    {
        $this->branch_id = $branch_id;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param Branch $branch
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setBranch(Branch $branch) : self
    {
        $this->branch_id = $branch->id;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getCategoryId(): int
    {
        return $this->category_id;
    }


    /**
     * @param int $category_id
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setCategoryId(int $category_id): self
    {
        $this->category_id = $category_id;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param Category $cat
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setCategory(Category $cat) : self
    {
        $this->category_id = $cat->id;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getTypeId(): int
    {
        return $this->type_id;
    }


    /**
     * @param int $type_id
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setTypeId(int $type_id): self
    {
        $this->type_id = $type_id;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param Type $type
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setType(Type $type) : self
    {
        $this->type_id = $type->id;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReg(): string
    {
        return $this->reg;
    }


    /**
     * @param string $reg
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setReg(string $reg): self
    {
        $this->reg = $reg;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMake(): string
    {
        return $this->make;
    }


    /**
     * @param string $make
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setMake(string $make): self
    {
        $this->make = $make;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getModel(): string
    {
        return $this->model;
    }


    /**
     * @param string $model
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setModel(string $model): self
    {
        $this->model = $model;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSpecification(): string
    {
        return $this->specification;
    }


    /**
     * @param string $specification
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setSpecification(string $specification): self
    {
        $this->specification = $specification;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDerivative(): string
    {
        return $this->derivative;
    }


    /**
     * @param string $derivative
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setDerivative(string $derivative): self
    {
        $this->derivative = $derivative;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEngineSize(): string
    {
        return $this->engine_size;
    }


    /**
     * @param string $engine_size
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setEngineSize(string $engine_size): self
    {
        $this->engine_size = $engine_size;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEngineType(): string
    {
        return $this->engine_type;
    }


    /**
     * @param string $engine_type
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setEngineType(string $engine_type): self
    {
        $this->engine_type = $engine_type;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTransmission(): string
    {
        return $this->transmission;
    }


    /**
     * @param string $transmission
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setTransmission(string $transmission): self
    {
        $this->transmission = $transmission;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getColour(): string
    {
        return $this->colour;
    }


    /**
     * @param string $colour
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setColour(string $colour): self
    {
        $this->colour = $colour;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getYear(): int
    {
        return $this->year;
    }


    /**
     * @param int $year
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setYear(int $year): self
    {
        $this->year = $year;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getMileage(): int
    {
        return $this->mileage;
    }


    /**
     * @param int $mileage
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setMileage(int $mileage): self
    {
        $this->mileage = $mileage;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isCommercial(): bool
    {
        return (bool)$this->commercial;
    }


    /**
     * @param bool $commercial
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setCommercial(bool $commercial): self
    {
        $this->commercial = (int)$commercial;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getSalesSiv(): float
    {
        return $this->sales_siv;
    }


    /**
     * @param float|int $sales_siv
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setSalesSiv(float $sales_siv = 0): self
    {
        $this->sales_siv = $sales_siv;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getRetail(): float
    {
        return $this->retail;
    }


    /**
     * @param float|int $retail
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setRetail(float $retail = 0): self
    {
        $this->retail = $retail;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getWebPrice(): float
    {
        return $this->web_price;
    }

    /**
     * @param float|int $web_price
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setWebPrice(float $web_price = 0): self
    {
        $this->web_price = $web_price;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSubHeading(): string
    {
        return $this->sub_heading;
    }


    /**
     * @param string $sub_heading
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setSubHeading(string $sub_heading): self
    {
        $this->sub_heading = $sub_heading;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAdvertisingNotes(): string
    {
        return $this->advertising_notes;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $advertising_notes
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setAdvertisingNotes(string $advertising_notes): self
    {
        $this->advertising_notes = $advertising_notes;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getManagerComments(): string
    {
        return $this->manager_comments;
    }


    /**
     * @param string $managerComments
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setManagerComments(string $managerComments): self
    {
        $this->manager_comments = $managerComments;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getPreviousPrice(): float
    {
        return $this->previous_price;
    }


    /**
     * @param float $previous_price
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setPreviousPrice(float $previous_price): self
    {
        $this->previous_price = $previous_price;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getGuideRetailPrice(): float
    {
        return $this->guide_retail_price;
    }


    /**
     * @param float $guide_retail_price
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setGuideRetailPrice(float $guide_retail_price): self
    {
        $this->guide_retail_price = $guide_retail_price;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAvailableForSale(): bool
    {
        return $this->available_for_sale;
    }


    /**
     * @param bool $available_for_sale
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setAvailableForSale(bool $available_for_sale): self
    {
        $this->available_for_sale = (int)$available_for_sale;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAdvertisedOnOwnWebsite(): bool
    {
        return $this->advertised_on_own_website;
    }


    /**
     * @param bool $advertised_on_own_website
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setAdvertisedOnOwnWebsite(bool $advertised_on_own_website): self
    {
        $this->advertised_on_own_website = (int)$advertised_on_own_website;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getBerths(): int
    {
        return $this->berths;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $berth
     */
    public function setBerths(int $berths): self
    {
        $this->berths = $berths;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getAxles(): int
    {
        return $this->axles;
    }


    /**
     * @param int $axles
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setAxles(int $axles): self
    {
        $this->axles = $axles;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLayoutType(): string
    {
        return $this->layout_type;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $layout_type
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setLayoutType(string $layout_type): self
    {
        $this->layout_type = $layout_type;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getWidth(): float
    {
        return $this->width;
    }


    /**
     * @param float $width
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setWidth(float $width): self
    {
        $this->width = $width;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getLength(): float
    {
        return $this->length;
    }


    /**
     * @param float $length
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setLength(float $length): self
    {
        $this->length = $length;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getHeight(): float
    {
        return $this->height;
    }


    /**
     * @param float $height
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setHeight(float $height): self
    {
        $this->height = $height;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getKimberleyUnitId(): int
    {
        return $this->kimberley_unit_id;
    }


    /**
     * @param int $kimberley_unit_id
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setKimberleyUnitId(int $kimberley_unit_id): self
    {
        $this->kimberley_unit_id = $kimberley_unit_id;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getKimberleyDateUpdated(): \DateTime
    {
        return $this->kimberley_date_updated;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $kimberley_date_updated
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setKimberleyDateUpdated(\DateTime $kimberley_date_updated): self
    {
        $this->kimberley_date_updated = $kimberley_date_updated;
        return $this;
    }


    

}
```

So i have the `HasOne` parts at the top to be able to use the model to get the `type` and `category`, but how would i do this to replace my query above with the where clause?

I have tried something like:

```
Caravan::with(['type','category'])->where('type.name','New');
```

This doesn't work, just says `type` doesn't exist in so many words.

So what i want to get back, is the model like i would just running say `Caravan::all()` which i would then be able to loop and use something like `$caravan->type->name`

**EDIT**

Answer below from Wahyu:

```
Caravan::with(['type' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'New');
}, 'category' => function($query) use ($category) {
        $query->where('name',ucwords(strtolower($category)));
    }])->orderBy($orderBy,$order);
```

This query runs fine however, it's bringing results back where type is Used as well as New so the query isn't working.

Also, looping the results, i still can't use the HasOne method in my model to do `$caravan->type->name`

However, `Caravan::all()` as a test allows me to use `$caravan->type->name` in the loop and that works ok, so the where query is still an issue

Comment: can you share the exact error? sidenote: why are you using setters/getters in an eloquent model? , they are not needed at all .

Comment: I also asked the same thing. Normally, only relations, mutators & casting exist in the model.

Comment: @GertB. because i am a symfony developer and i don't like how laravel uses magic methods, i prefer getters and setters. Magic methods are so inefficient it's unreal and make it harder to follow the code.

Comment: @GertB. I suppose you have a point with laravel though it uses a lot of magic methods so my getters and setters are actually redundant, laravel is inefficient by it's overall design anyway, it uses multiple return types everywhere and magic methods everywhere, it's poorly constructed from the start, but makes it quick to develop which is the only reason i'm learning it.

Comment: @noname ok, for each its own, It looks like a lot of unneeded code.  But in that case there is no point in using Laravel instead of Symfony. Saying Laravel is poorly constructed... Lets agree to disagree.

Comment: @GertB. not my choice to use laravel! but yeh, agree to disagree is good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a recent version of Laravel you can do something like:

```php
Caravan::query()
    ->whereRelation('type', 'name', 'New')
    ->whereRelation('category', 'name', ucwords(strtolower($category)))
    ->orderBy($orderBy, $order)
    ->get();
```

Otherwise, you can use the eloquent [whereHas()](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method to achieve the same result.

```php
Caravan::query()
    ->whereHas('type', fn (Builder $query) => $query->where('name', 'New'))
    ->whereHas('category', fn (Builder $query) => $query->where('name', ucwords(strtolower($category))))
    ->orderBy($orderBy, $order)
    ->get();
```

Looking at your model relations I think your relations should be `one to many` instead of `one to one`. If so your relations should be:

```php
public function type()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Type::class);
}

public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

Comment: i didn't realise HasOne was a one to one, i actually thought it was a ManyToOne, i'll give what you've said a shot, thanks, i'll be back.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish by passing an array of relationships to the `with` method where the array key is a relationship name and the array value is a closure that adds additional constraints to the eager loading query:

```
Caravan::with(['type' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'New');
}, 'category'])->get();
```

##### Update (different question):

> i still can't use the `HasOne` method in my model to do `$caravan->type->name`

```
public function type() : HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(Type::class, 'id', 'type_id');
}
```

So, you can access the `Type` model from `Caravan` model. You can define the **inverse** of a `hasOne` relationship using the `belongsTo` method:

```
public function type()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Type::class);
}
```

When invoking the `type` method, Eloquent will attempt to find a `Type` model that has an `id` which matches the `type_id` column on the `Caravan` model.

Comment: in laravel 8.5 and up not sure about the version you can do this not? `->whereRelation('category', 'name', '=', 'new')`

Comment: If you would like to query for a relationship's existence with a single, simple where condition attached to the relationship query, you may find it more convenient to use the `whereRelation` and `whereMorphRelation` methods.

Comment: @WahyuKristianto what is whereMorphRelation ? This is so much simpler in doctrine lol

Comment: @WahyuKristianto The code you provided works, but how does this work with the model method type() with my HasOne ? I tried to loop them and do $c->type->name but it says it's undefined, i thought the point in the HasOne method is to link it to the relationship?

Comment: @WahyuKristianto i've updated my question, your code isn't working, it's bringing results where type isn't "New"

Comment: Can you change `$this->hasOne(Type::class, 'type_id', 'id')` @noname?

Comment: @WahyuKristianto well no, type_id is the local key to Caravan?

Comment: @noname second argument is `foreign_key` and third argument is `local_key`

Comment: @noname check my update